# RPC Serialization policy file under AppEngine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, rpc

The GWT / AppEngine RPC interface is eating at me!  I get errors such as this:

`INFO: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: UserService: ERROR: The serialization policy file '/55585D0849A4549E3FCE91B33725B02F.gwt.rpc' was not found; did you forget to include it in this deployment?`

every time I start the Devserver.  I have correctly set the `public-root` in `appengine-web.xml` (the rest of the application is served OK except for the `.gwt.rpc` files).

```
  <static-files>
    <include path="**" />
    <include path="**.nocache.*" expiration="0s" />
    <include path="**.rpc" expiration="0s" />
    <include path="**.cache.*" expiration="365d" />
  </static-files>

  <resource-files>
    <include path="**.gwt.rpc" />
  </resource-files>
```

What am I doing wrong? Help please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some experimenting, here is what I came up with:

- Do not forget to have the `.rpc` files included in the appengine deployment (`appengine-web.xml` file) and beware of caching issues! (e.g. changes in serialization policy)
- Better not to use `public-root` tag in `appengine-web.xml`: drop the `welcome file` (e.g. index.html) in `/` of the `war` directory and make the appropriate change for GWT to find its files
- Update the servlets `url-pattern` tags to point inside GWT generated directory inside the `war` directory
- For servlets associated with `tasks` (i.e. `web hooks`), do not change the `url-pattern`

Hence, the only place that requires some knowledge of the GWT generated folder resides in `web.xml`.  Of course, the `welcome-file` of the GWT project must also be adapted.

Hope this helps somebody

Comment: Hi, I'm seeing similar errors in my App Engine log. Could you elaborate more on 'beware of caching issues! (e.g. changes in serialization policy)'? Thanks.

Comment: caching of .rpc files on the client side i.e. changes in the .rpc must be propagated.

Comment: I got this error by having a <resource-files> block that didn't include "**.gwt.rpc". I removed it and it works now.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem on the deployed GAE server and it wasn't until I added the rpc include for the resource-files section that the error went away. Here's what I ended up with:

```
<resource-files>
    <include path="/resources/**" />
    <include path="**.gwt.rpc"/>
</resource-files>

<static-files>
  <include path="**" />
  <include path="**.nocache.*" expiration="0s" />
  <include path="**.cache.*" expiration="365d" />
  <exclude path="**.gwt.rpc"/>
</static-files>
```